# Laravel search query optimization

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-optimization, query-builder

hope you are doing good!

I have more than 4500 `businesses` in my database. Each `business` **hasMany** `tags`. So I have my main search input in navbar. When user submits any string via that search input I want to display all businesses that contain this `string` in any of their `tags` **or/and** in it's `name` field.

Example: When `string`  = **ab**. It must display first 20 `businesses` that contains `string` **ab** in any of their `tag` name **or/and** `name` field.

Result:

1. `Name`: Nur**ab**is `Tags`: Alcoholic Beverages
2. `Name`: Boirs `Tags`: Mobile Phones, Mobile Phone Accessories, T**ab**lets
3. `Name`: B**ab**ilon `Tags`: C**abl**e TV, Mobile Network Operators
4. ......

This Eloquesnt/DB query was generated and executed

```
$businesses = Business::
            ->select('businesses.*')
            ->leftJoin('business_tag', 'businesses.id', '=', 'business_tag.business_id')
            ->leftJoin('tags', 'business_tag.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
            ->orWhere("tags.{$this->lang}_name", 'LIKE', "%$str%")
            ->orWhere('businesses.name', 'LIKE', "%$str%")
            
            ->where('businesses.status', true)
            ->groupBy('businesses.id')
            ->with(['tags'])
            ->withCount(['reviews as rating' => function($query){ 
                $query->select(DB::raw('round(avg(rating), 1)')); 
            }])
            ->withCount('reviews')
            ->with(['reviews' => function($query){
                $query->latest();
            }])
            ->with(['images' => function ($query)
                {
                    $query->where('avatar', true);
                }])
            ->paginate(20);
```

The problem is that it took **21.05s** to execute. This is what my debugger shows. These are two queries that took most of the time:

**6.24s**

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `businesses` 
left join `business_tag` on `businesses`.`id` = `business_tag`.`business_id` 
left join `tags` on `business_tag`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` 
where (`tags`.`en_name` LIKE '%ab%' or `businesses`.`name` LIKE '%ab%') 
and `businesses`.`status` = 1 group by `businesses`.`id`
```

and **14.78s**

```
select `businesses`.*, 
     (select round(avg(rating), 1) from `reviews` 
      where `businesses`.`id` = `reviews`.`business_id` and `status` = 1) as `rating`,

     (select count(*) from `reviews` where `businesses`.`id` = `reviews`.`business_id` 
      and `status` = 1) as `reviews_count` from `businesses` 
left join `business_tag` on `businesses`.`id` = `business_tag`.`business_id` 
left join `tags` on `business_tag`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` 
where (`tags`.`en_name` LIKE '%ab%' or `businesses`.`name` LIKE '%ab%') 
and `businesses`.`status` = 1 group by `businesses`.`id` limit 20 offset 0
```

But when I comment that tag part like so

```
$businesses = Business::
            ->select('businesses.*')
            // ->leftJoin('business_tag', 'businesses.id', '=', 'business_tag.business_id')
            // ->leftJoin('tags', 'business_tag.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
            // ->orWhere("tags.{$this->lang}_name", 'LIKE', "%$str%")
            ->orWhere('businesses.name', 'LIKE', "%$str%")
```

I takes **40.47ms** to execute.
And if I comment name part instead like so

```
$businesses = Business::
            ->select('businesses.*')
            ->leftJoin('business_tag', 'businesses.id', '=', 'business_tag.business_id')
            ->leftJoin('tags', 'business_tag.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
            ->orWhere("tags.{$this->lang}_name", 'LIKE', "%$str%")
            // ->orWhere('businesses.name', 'LIKE', "%$str%")
```

It takes **90.84ms**

Now the question is: **Is there any way to optimize this query?**
Thank you in advance! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below.See how much time it take time to execute.Aslo instead of lefjoin you can create `belongsToMany` relationship in `Business Model` for `Tags`

```
$businesses = Business::
        select('businesses.*')
        ->leftJoin('business_tag', 'businesses.id', '=', 'business_tag.business_id')
        ->leftJoin('tags', 'business_tag.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
        ->where(function ($q)use($str){
            $q->where('businesses.status', true);
            $q->orWhere("tags.{$this->lang}_name", 'LIKE', "%$str%");
            $q->orWhere('businesses.name', 'LIKE', "%$str%");
        })
        ->groupBy('businesses.id')
        ->withCount(['reviews as rating' => function($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw('round(avg(rating), 1)'));
        }])
        ->withCount('reviews')
        ->with(['reviews' => function($query){
            $query->latest();
        }])
        ->with(['images' => function ($query)
        {
            $query->where('avatar', true);
        }])
        ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: it took 21.98s and yes I have belongsToMany relationship but it seems that joining is taking less time to execute

Comment: okay.since you have already leftjoin tags so remove  ->with(['tags'])

Comment: okay.np.lets see if some others answer might help you to improve your query